# How to remove everything up until the first character in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm getting a string which returns an integer first, followed by a series of spaces and then the string I want. My goal is to just get "Moonwalking with Einstein" in this example. I'm using Javascript. What's the best way to achieve this?

```
            2                                               







            Moonwalking with Einstein
```

Comment: What are your criteria for “the best way” and what have you even tried? What didn’t work?

Comment: This matches the digits but not sure about the spaces.

Comment: @Azamantes This returns `MoonwalkingwithEinstein` with all the line breaks before that.

Comment: It sounds like *Einstein on the beach*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's replace function for this.

It looks like you are looking to replace digits and instances of two or more consecutive spaces

`\d` - Matches any digit

`|` - Or conditional symbol

`\s` - Matches any whitespace character

`{2,}` - Matches two or more

`/g` - Matches all instances

```js
var string = " 2                    Moonwalking with Einstein"

string = string.replace(/\d|\s{2,}/g, '')

var result = document.getElementById("result");

result.innerHTML = string;
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will accept your answer when it allows me to.

Comment: This will remove all digits in the text below, if there are any, and it won’t remove the first space before the digit in this example.

Comment: string = string.replace(/^\s/g, '').replace(/\d|\s{2,}/g, '');

Answer (score 1):

You can use a str replace with a regex like this:

```
^[^A-Za-z]+
or
/^[^a-z]+/i
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/kN3zS3/1)**

```
var str = '            2                                               \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n            Moonwalking with Einstein';
var result = str.replace(/^[^A-Za-z]+/, '');
```

The idea is to match whatever starts with a character that is not A-Z and a-z and replace it with an empty string and to keep what you want.